# Mysql Запрос

Tags: mysql

Помогите пожалуйста составить запрос
есть таблица вида:

```
+----+-----+-------+---------+

| id | uid | value | time    |

+----+-----+-------+---------+

1   |   1   |   *   |   13:10

2   |   2   |   *   |   13:10

3   |   1   |   *   |   14:10

4   |   2   |   *   |   14:10
```

и т.д.

uid - идентификаторы пользователя (одни и те же).
нужно получить все value для всех uid в 14:10!!! (последнее время записи)
те группы где записываются значения value для всех uid чередуются по времени

Comment: зы последнее time неизвестно...

Comment: @script_kid, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select uid from table1 where time=(select time from table1 desc id limit 1)` ?

Comment: select uid from table1 where time=(select time from table1 desc id limit 1) ?
 Правильно, только теперь укажи там по какому значению фильтровать

Comment: select uid from table1 where time=(select time from table1 order by id desc limit 1)


так работает спасибо)